# Flutter GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:8:9: error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found on m1 mac

Tags: flutter

I am unable to build a project on IOS. My project and code is running on macbook pro intel but i just installed the latest version of flutter on m1 macbook pro and now the project is not running.
I am getting `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:8:9: error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found`

I tried to create new project and copy the files but it is showing same error.
I removed pod files and reinstall it. I also tried to build from xcode after making sure that `Build Active Architecture is YES`.
Tried flutter clean many times but still getting this issue. `Flutter doctor -v` is all green and good. I have downloaded latest from `flutter pub get`. Found similar questions here but with no proper answer.